# Lista de clientes da DB na pagina do programa em C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, paginação, link

Meu problema é o seguinte, eu não sei fazer com que apareça na tela do usuário uma lista com limite X de clientes de uma DB, vou tentar colocar em tópicos para um melhor entendimento

1 - A lista de clientes deve aparecer de 10 em 10 
2 - Quando atingido os 10 teria, um botão ou seta para a próxima pagina
3 - Vi uns tutoriais com gridview, mas não é isso que busco
4 - Quando aparecerem devem vir como um linklabel 
5 - Quando clicado o linklabel a id do cliente deve ser passada para outro form

Espero que isso seja possível, se alguém souber me explicar como fazer fico agradecido.
Não sei se faz diferença mas uso o Visual Studio 2010 professional, e uso o sql server

Comment: Henrique, se possível poste o que já tentou ate agora, fica mais facil para as pessoas te ajudarem.

Comment: Não tentei nada por que eu não tenho idéia de como fazer isso, eu to procurando no youtube e fóruns pra ver se encontro algo relacionado

Comment: Você quer fazer isto em uma aplicação web certo? Você já consegue buscar os clientes no banco de dados?

Comment: Não, é um programinha de pc mesmo sem relação com browser algum, e sim consigo buscar na DB

Answer (score -1):

Cara, pelo o que eu entendi, você quer que mostre uma lista de 10 usuario e depois passe a pagina dessa lista, é isso?

Eu fiz um exemplo usando PagedList.
vou deixar um exemplo de como eu consegui fazer.

Na controller eu fiz assim:
using PagedList;

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? pagina)
    {
        var ListaEventos = db.Objetos.Tolist();
        int PaginaTamanho = 4; //<<<<<Tamanho de objetos na pagina(no seu caso coloca 10)
        int paginaNumero = (pagina ?? 1);


        return View(ListaEventos.ToPagedList(paginaNumero, PaginaTamanho));
```

Já no html eu so coloquei esse assim:

Página @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)

```
@Model.PageCount

@if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("<<", "Index", new { pagina = 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }, new { type = "button", @class = "btn btn-info", style = "background-color: #009688" })

    @Html.Raw(" ");

    @Html.ActionLink("< Previous", "Index", new { pagina = Model.PageNumber - 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter },new {type= "button",  @class = "btn btn-info", style = "background-color: #009688" })
}
else
{
    @:<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="background-color: #009688"><<</button>
    @Html.Raw(" ");
    @:<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="background-color: #009688">Previous</button>
}
@if (Model.HasNextPage)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Next ", "Index", new { pagina = Model.PageNumber + 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter } , new { type = "button", @class = "btn btn-info" , style = "background-color: #009688" })
    @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink(">>", "Index", new { pagina = Model.PageCount, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }, new { type = "button", @class = "btn btn-info", style = "background-color: #009688" })
}
else
{
    @:<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="background-color: #009688">Next</button>
    @Html.Raw(" ")
    @:<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="background-color: #009688">>></button>
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: mas ai não vai abrir em um browser?